# Jenkins + Grails or Jenkins + Gradle + Grails

Tags: grails, jenkins, gradle

I have a grails project. I want to set up some CI for it. Are my better off calling grails commands directly from Jenkins or using Jenkins to call Gradle to call Grails commands.

The reason I ask is that when using Gradle with Grails most Gradle stuff just calls out directly to Grails commands.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The easiest is to use the (built-in) grails wrapper (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#wrapper).

You would then run

```
./grailsw refresh-dependencies
./grailsw test-app
```

First line to setup (install all plugins etc.) grails and second to run your tests.

The advantage of grails wrapper is that it takes care of downloading & installing the correct grails version. Which is very useful if you upgrade grails. You don't have to do anything on your ci server.

There is also a grails plugin for jenkins (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Grails+Plugin) that supports the grails wrapper.

Comment: be advice, for current version of grails (3.x+) now supports gradle and it uses a different set of `tasks`.